# How to style mixed django form better

Tags: css, django, django-forms

I have theese two forms:

```
class InitialForm(Form):
    trn = IntegerField(widget=NumberInput, required = False)
    klient = ChoiceField(choices=KLIENTS, required = False)

class SecondForm(Form):
    faktura = CharField(max_length = 200, required=False)
```

In the form I'm mixing `django` forms and pure html `select` (because I needed to pull out some data from a database)

```
<form method="POST" novalidate>
        {% csrf_token %}

        <label for="{{ form.klient.id_for_label }}">Klient:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
        {{ form.klient }}
        <br><br>

        <label for="programs">Program: </label>
        <select id="programselect" name="programs">
        {% for option in options %}
            <option value="{{ option.0}}">{{ option.1 }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
        </select>
        <br><br>

        <label for="{{ form.trn.id_for_label }}">Trn:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </label>
        {{ form.trn }}
        <br><br>

        <label for="{{ form2.faktura.id_for_label }}">Faktura:&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
        {{ form2.faktura }}
        <br>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary">Search</button>
</form>
```

So far, I tried it with `&nbsp&` to have the `inputs` above each other.

How would you style it better with `CSS`?

Comment: Since this relates to your UI, are you already using some front-end framework, such as Bootstrap?  This may affect answers considerably.  You may also want to look into the Crispy template pack.  Good explanation here:  https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/11/28/advanced-form-rendering-with-django-crispy-forms.html

Comment: Yes, I'm already using some styles for table from Bootstrap.

Comment: In that case I would highly recommend using django-crispy-forms to style your forms.  It's a very popular package, and well maintainted.  https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: I can use e.g. `{{ form.klient |as_crispy_field }}` but what about the `<select>`?

Comment: I added an answer with how you might handle the `<select>` tag using model forms and initial values from the database.  Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using the crispy template pack for styling, you could create a model form class and give the `programs` field initial "options" from the database, using a query from whatever model you're storing the "options" on. Here's an example, using some assumptions about your database schema:

```
        class ProgramForm(forms.ModelForm):
            class Meta: 
                fields = ['program']
                model = MyRecord

            def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
                super(ProgramForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
                self.fields['program'].queryset = Option.objects.filter(some_field=True).order_by("option_name")
```

Using this kind of solution, you're using your backend model form class to handle passing the "option" data, and doing all your styling in the html with crispy.  Note that if you're using two separate forms, pass them to your template with different names, like:

```
{{form.klient|as_crispy_field}}
{{program_form.program|as_crispy_field}}
```

Additionally, you can use Django's widgets to add functionality to your options selector, for example if you wanted checkboxes instead of a dropdown select (ForeignKey vs M2M, let's say).

If you can do none of that and must use this HTML structure and backend approach, you can still target the form with CSS, for example something like:

```
<style>
#this-label span {

        margin-right: 100px;
    }

</style>

<label for="{{ form.trn.id_for_label }}" id="this-label"> <span>Trn:</span> </label>
```

...will add space to the right of "Trn:".  This is just one way of doing that, but you could add a class to the span element and target multiple such tags.

Comment: But I don't use `forms.ModelForm`, I use only the `<select>` in html. I need to style it somehow independently on `forms.Form` or `forms.ModelForm`.

Comment: Yes, my suggestion is that you use `forms.ModelForm` in your back end to populate the dropdown with your database.  You can still target the label element with CSS for styling, perhaps by giving your label an ID.  `<label id="something">`.  You may also try writing some span elements in your html to target those with CSS, for example `<span class="someClass">Trn:</span>`.  If you use crispy, your labels will be generated for you, but you can still style them further by targeting their IDs and/or classes.

Comment: I can't use `self.fields['program'].queryset = Option.objects.filter(some_field=True).order_by("option_name")` because I'm using raw queries in the view. `with connections["mssql_database"].cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute("select distinct a, b ...")
        options = cursor.fetchall()
    context = {
                'form': initial_form,
                'form2': second_form,
                'options': options,
              }`

Comment: Understood.  I updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks, I see I have to use this approach and style one thing with `crispy` and one with plain CSS. Are there some advantages over using `&nbsp;` as I do?

Comment: In general, using CSS will give you far greater control and maintainability in lieu of using hard-coded non-breaking-spaces like `&nbsp;`.  I use them sometimes if I need more than one, and the situation may reoccur, it's best to use some CSS.  You may also want some vertical space or some other formatting, which only CSS will do.  Nothing wrong with mixing crispy and basic html, as long as you're comfortable with the result.  You can also further style crispy forms by targeting the generated selectors with CSS.  Sounds like you have some interesting requirements with raw queries and all.